# How to create an app to make folders and store images in it using nativescript?

Tags: nativescript

can anyone share any link of creating an app to store images in a particular album using nativescript ?
i have tried searching in google but didn't find anything related to this. so,it would be helpful if anyone shares me a github link or any other.

Answer (score 0):

I used [this link](https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/how-to-save-an-imagesource-object-to-the-devices-photo-library-on-both-ios-and-android/1126) when developing a NativeScript JavaScript function to save screen shots to the device's photo gallery. Good luck!